# Zend framework 2 + composer install error

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

I am newbie to Zend and php

**While trying to install zf2 i am facing the issue while composer.phar is installed**

I have cloned the following repository  git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git zf2-tutorial

Then moved into xampp\htdocss

php composer.phar self-update --> This is working and when I run the next command i get an exception.

```
$ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.2.1)
    Downloading: 100%
```

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor/zendframework/zendframework/30d4a3b0d6
>   7fcce22fce0aeedb6f1573.1' is not a zip archive.

Answer (score 1):

On a short note, this is a problem that i fell into, basically you need to do,
 **php composer.phar install** and then **composer.phar update** and then **composer.phar self update**. What i found out was that when you do **php composer.phar self-update** you do not need to do **php composer.phar install** as self update command will install and update(both). Try running a program.

Comment: Thanks, i was trying to fix this issue for hours and finally works.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use following steps to install Zend Framework 2 with Doctrine or ZF2 without doctrine. Following commands are tested successfully on *nix platform.

**To install ZF2 Without doctrine ORM run following commands in your working directory**

```
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-developer-tools:dev-master
cp vendor/zendframework/zend-developer-tools/config/zenddevelopertools.local.php.dist config/autoload/zdt.local.php

chmod 777 data/cache/
```

//enable modules in config/application.config.php file

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'Application',
    ),
    // [...]
);
```

### **To install ZF2 With doctrine run following commands in your working directory**

```
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar require doctrine/doctrine-orm-module:0.7.*  
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-developer-tools:dev-master
cp vendor/zendframework/zend-developer-tools/config/zenddevelopertools.local.php.dist config/autoload/zdt.local.php


chmod 777 data/cache/
```

//enable modules in config/application.config.php file

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'Application',
    ),
    // [...]
);
```

Command Line

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your composer cache contains corrupted items. You should clear your composer cache and try again. The cache directory is called .composer/cache and is located in your composer home directory. Just clear it and re-try.